# how to import colored mesh from meshlab to unity!(may thouth 3ds max)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, meshlab

I'm very new.I have a ply file,with some faces and colored point cloud.My  finial aim is use unity to import this mesh with color!
I find some way ,it seems need 3ds max.But i even make mesh have color in 3ds max.
I tried :
1 In mashleb,filters-texture-per vertex texture function and convert PerVertex UV into perwedge UV.And i get a obj with mtl(only 1KB).Of courese ,it doesn't works.
2 I try filters-texture-transefer Vertex color to texture .and i get i png.But it seems only a side color of mesh.
3 I try filters-color creation and prcession-transfer color:vertex to face.And i get a obj with a little large mtl file.This action make it is very slow to open this obj file in meshlab and 3ds max and unity.And it doesn't works.
I think the color system of 3ds max and unity is different from meshlab.But i have no idea how to do!Any suggesion is OK !Thanks!

---

It seems after filters-texture-transefer Vertex color to texture,and save it .It can have some texture but wrong like this:  [pictures here](https://github.com/lixz123007/picture/blob/master/error1.png)
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLUII.png)
I think some thing wrong with getting texture.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found ansner in youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wP_e37t7PI
3. Filters -> Texture -> Parametrization: Trivial Per-Triangle

4. Save project
5. Filters -> Texture -> Transfer Vertex Attributes to Texture
6. Export mesh as obj. file

I don't know reason but it really works.